# Почему нельзя добавить fxcid в Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, scene-builder

На первой картинке мой Scene Builder,
а на второй скриншот из Ютуба, похоже у всех кроме меня 
есть поле вставки id.
(версия IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.4 )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

sample.fxml:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <HBox prefHeight="494.0" prefWidth="650.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="button1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickMethod" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="61.0" text="Button" />
            <Button fx:id="button2" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button2" />
            <TableView fx:id="tab1" prefHeight="494.0" prefWidth="284.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="Vert" prefWidth="75.0" text="Ver" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="Horz" prefWidth="75.0" text="Hor" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>

         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Как вариант, Вы можете задать атрибут `fx:id` непосредственно в `fxml`-файле.

Answer (score 0):

установите `scene-builder` от [gluonhq](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/), там все есть.

Comment: Установил scene-builder от gluonhq, но в самой IDEA ничего не поменялось. Да, когда этот scene-builder открывается отдельно, там есть fxid, но он не связан с текущим проектом. Вопрос остается - как люди имеют нормальный scene-builder прямо в IDEA  ?

Answer (score 0):

Я вообще не пользуюсь билдером. Все, включая id, отлично и просто прописывается в коде или в самом fxml рядом, в папке проекта.

```
<TextArea fx:id="tArea" 
        editable="false" 
        VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
```

И вообще, как по мне, билдер нужен лишь когда надо создать огромный и мощный, сложный проект и нет времени на ручные правки. Простые программы легко создаются вручную, за несколько часов.

В любом случае, тебе придется пользоваться ручками в fxml готовом, так или иначе, так что собирай его, клади в рабочую область и дописывай id сам тогда.